# What changed from HSD to HSD2.0?

Tags: edition-comparison, hc-svnt-dracones

I bought HC SVNT DRACONES some half a dozen years ago and never got to play it. I just now stumbled upon the fact that they published a second edition in 2019, branded HC SVNT DRACONES 2.0.

Did the lore of the game evolve between the editions, or are the changes mainly about the mechanical system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bought the 2.0 to compare them, and here's what I found

### Opening them side by side...

The title changed more than just slapping a 2.0 to the name: the subtitle "Post-Human Tabletop Role Play" was dropped from v.1.1 to 2.0. So was the preluding Churchill quote on the inner cover. But that's nitpicky.

#### The Credits page

The v.1.1 lists Pierce Fraser as the Creator, the v.2.0 is credited to Emily Fraser. I can't find a reason for the name change or even if it is the same person.

Besides the creator/copyright holder, no editor is named for 2.0, while 1.1 names one. Among the artists, none of the names appears in both editions.

HSD did rely on a system dubbed *8-10-12 check system* while HSD 2.0 uses the *Staggered Scale check system*.

#### Table of contents, length & order

HSD 1.1 had only the major H1 headers on the table of contents organized in three sections. The major sections cover Lore, Character generation (including all options and equipment), and Gameplay rules. One of the 290 pages not counting the covers is dedicated to it.

HSD 2 has a much more detailed table of contents, displaying the sections, and headers down to rank 3. Intro, Systems (Rules), Adventuring, and then several smaller sections for various sub-systems and equipment fill two full pages. There are 344 pages not counting covers.

#### Intro

Besides the phrasing, nothing changed in the intro to what is an RPG and the goals. Both are about exploring humanity as the heirs of it, and the designer makes that clear:

> They [the characters] are human inside, but they
> lack human form, human context, human history and
> human tradition. All they have left is the husk that is
> Earth hanging overhead and the single, clear message:
>
> “These people did it this way, and it destroyed them.”
>
> HSD is not about getting in touch with your
> animal side, as so many anthropomorphic systems
> encourage. You’re welcome to, if that’s the way you’d
> like to play it, but the setting is intended to allow you
> to get in touch with your human side instead. Not the
> culture you were raised in, or the history you’ve experienced;
> not whether you’re black, white, red, yellow,
> or polychromatic; not your geographical history or the
> wars your species has been in; your humanity. Just that.

This hasn't changed. In fact, that snipped is exactly unchanged in either.

The biggest change to HSD 2.0 is, that the part about any mechanical rules was pushed out of this section. So, you find the introduction to the idea of the game, what is a game, a little terminology lexicon, the role of Guide (GM) and a *the GM is always right* table rule.

#### The Lore

The most jarring difference you are faced in the Lore section is, that it is told entirely differently. It's rewritten, a different angle...

| HSD | HSD 2.0 |
| --- | --- |
| Start point is about 21st Century with the creation of some kind of very extensive computer network that interlinks people globally and results in conflict. The game names the first time point in relation to *now*: 700 years ago, autonomous mining technology arose. It created massive corporate sprawls, leading to corporate law superseding national laws. It came to the Humanity conquers space, or at least moves to incorporate Mars into its sphere of influence. Now, mars colonized, the first genetic hybrid pets are introduced. | The lore section starts directly with the advent of genetic manipulation and explains how the fractured historic record establishes the designer hybrid pets first, then bipedal pets and how this ultimately leads to the origin of *Vectors*. |
| As Government control on the creation of bipedal animal pets tightened and they were meant to be eradicated on earth, MarsCo receives a package of research data. They researched the technology, leading to giving them sentience. | At some point, MarsCo declared its independence from the earth, as the nations of earth spiraled into regulatory controlling the genetically manipulated pet market and meant to eradicate non-sentient bipedal creatures. Independent, MarsCo started to research sentient, long-living anthropomorphic genetic manipulation of humans - called *Vectors*. The result was a truly sentient humanoid with citizenship. |
| Faced with a truly sentient anthropomorphic race, Earth declared those to be Non-Citizen *Personae Non Grata*, while MarsCo made them *native* Citizens. The divide made Earth governments unhappy, and after a legal battle if MarsCo was independent or not, communications simply stopped 5 years after the first Vector was created. Earth turned to chaos and riot, and a year later turned to war. It became an all-out war between the rapidly uniting governments of earth under the banner of Terra Firma versus the corporations, both sides armed with weapons of mass destruction. Terra Firma didn't manage a swift victory and ended up collapsing economically. | With the first Vectors made, moral dilemma lead to turmoil on earth, governments tried to point out that MarsCo wasn't independent and under their jurisdiction. Corporations in League with MarsCo ended up fighting against national governments in a global war,... |
| MarsCo went on to expand the portfolio of Vectors. While earth devolved into warfare, the first generation of Vectors were still kids of 7. Conventional warfare turned into nuclear one when the conflict went into year 3 (about 8-9 years after the initial announcement of Vectors). Missiles struck pretty much everywhere, a hybrid of baseline Humans and Vectors emerged and the last shuttle to Mars all launched within a single year. Terra Firma tried to attack MarsCo and succeeded in hitting the spaceport with a nuke. Tragic happened and Mars was fully isolated while the earth was consumed in warfare and nuclear fire. But as Terra Firma seemed to win on earth, someone - it's unclear if it's MarsCo or a remaining corporate town - unleashed Hydra. A computer virus able to control any digital asset, it embedded in *every* computer system on earth. Terra Firma wanted to discuss terms as Hydra controlled all the remaining nuclear arsenal. Too late: Hydra started launching nukes only 8 hours after it had successfully gained control of the arsenals. 6 years later, it ran out, and the earth was completely sterilized. Humanity on earth had been eradicated when the first generation of Vectors turned 14, the bombardment stopped when they turned 15. With baseline humans destined to extinction, MarsCo humans turned to become Hemi-Vectors. | ... while MarsCo went on to expand the portfolio of Vectors. It's huge and most of a chapter, displaying the timeline of what came when and its benefits. Besides Vectors, which only can show one animal's traits morphologically, sentient machines in Vector shape are present, called Cogs. They emerged 70 years after the end of Humanity. Blips are the last kind of sentient lifeform in colonized space, designed biological lifeforms that are sterile - and show a true mix of traits from different animals. They're rare and apparently relatively recent. The narration stops here and all information is gained from a few timeline charts for Earth and other bodies. Hydra is responsible for the destruction of Earth, but seen as having extinct itself in the fireball. |
| Biodiversity and terraforming on Mars continued. Tests of Ovl Vectors failed, but other avians vunction. The baseline human population on Mars fell to less than a percent about 40 years after the earth had ceased nuking itself. 150 years after the end of the global war, orbital surveillance showed horrific creatures roaming the post-nuclear wastelands. A Lunar colony was established to monitor Earth, and it housed the last of the baseline humans. On a trip to earth they were killed by the monstrous wildlife. About 200 years after this trip (we're about 365 years after the end of the war), an attempt to reclaim earth was made, but it failed. Instead, Vectors spread to the outer solar system and Venus successfully. On Europa, they encountererd an alien relic. The scouts reporting it talked in their last transmission about "Hydra", then went rogue and block access to the relic since. | Luna Colony is established about 150 years after the fall by the last baseline humans. An earth colony is attempted but destroyed after 15 years. Luna Colony prospers, and another attempt of checking on Earth fails. Mars finishes terraforming, Venus is terraformed and colonized, so is Europa, Ganymede and other bodies. Europa encounters an ancient relic, the scouts transmit "Hydra" and then block access to it. |
| About 500 years after the first vector was born, Earth returned to limelight when something tried to launch from it and blew up in the atmosphere. Researchers went there and returned. In Luna colony, those returners turned into monsters and Luna Colony was lost. Some monsters made it to Mars, but were repelled. Those researchers destined for Venus were blown up as a precaution. Earth and Luna were declared Off-Limits permanent quarantine zones. | About 500 years after humanity died out, a ship explodes in Earth Orbit. Researchers go there, return and... Luna Colony is lost by the returners turning monsters. Mars fences off the same monsters, the Venus shuttle is blown up in transit. Earth and Lunar are declared Off-Limits Quarantaine. Over 200 years, Earth turns a red crystalline structure and some kind of tendril grows to connect it to Lunar, similarly encased in red. Europa is a scientist cloister that studies genetics, the creatures that attacked Luna and Mars, as well as alien lifeforms called Foea first encountered in Europa's waters... |

##### Summary & Comparison

HSD 2.0 cuts out the prelude, but goes much more into detail about social society and how the different locations fared. Earth is much more shrouded in mystery, but each place is much more fleshed out. Things that appeared in subsequent books for HSD have been pushed into the core lore and have been integrated. There's no major conflicting information between the two sources, the timeline hasn't been advanced, or at least not noticeably. All the information conflict might stem from the different, in both cases unnamed, narrator.

### Rules

The two systems are totally different and need major retooling from old material to be comparable.

- HSD uses a d8, d10 or d12 depending on the four statistics being set to the appropriate die in character generation, and then rolling as many dice as you have points in a statistic. Then add a proficiency modifier to each of the rolled dice: if the sum of modifier+roll is 8 or above, it's a success. You count successes to determine how well you made it.
- HSD 2.0 only has three Stats with two facets, resulting in 6 traits. You always roll two dice and add the proficiency, and if the sum of all is 12 or more you succeed. Depending on if your trait (a scale of 1-5) is better or worse than the difficulty (a scale of 0 to 6) you roll between 2d4 and 2d12.